# On Mac OS X 10.5 what determines PATH value before /etc/profile?

Tags: macos

While investigating the process described on the path_helper man page I was surprised to find that the value of PATH upon entry to /etc/profile seems to have already been customized per user. I can't seem to find anything documenting this behavior. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from Apple documentation:

On login, the loginwindow application looks for a special property list file with the name environment.plist. This file must be located in a directory called .MacOSX at the root of the user’s home directory. The path to this file is as follows:

~/.MacOSX/environment.plist

If an environment.plist file exists, loginwindow looks for keys that are children of the root element. For each of these keys, loginwindow registers an environment variable of the same name and assigns it the value of the key

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely an import piece of the puzzle! However it looks like there's also a default in place when that plist is not present. What I'm seeing is

/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/<username>

I'm not seeing any documentation for this. Am I still not using the appropriate search criteria?